# Can I use an Oracle trigger to force a varchar column to fit column width?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I have an application which is occasionally being passed data which causes it to fail with ORA-12899 error trying to insert the record into a varchar(2000) column on an Oracle 11g database.  )In some cases it is trying to insert a field of more than 4000 characters.)

In the longer term, I will request a change to the application to prevent this happening, but meanwhile I need a short-term fix to allow the record to be saved, truncating the data to 2000 characters.

I've experimented with a "before insert" trigger (which works fine when truncating it from say 1500 to 1000 characters), but what I've found is that where the data is more than 2000 characters (i.e. more than the column length) the insert still fails with ORA-12899.

Is there any way round this, other than changing the database column to a CLOB?

Comment: Is the application connecting to the DB as the table owner, or referring to the table with a schema prefix? If not - so it's using a synonym = are you allowed to create a view as the user it *does* connect as?

Comment: Hi Alex, I think this must be the answer to some different question?  I'm not asking about rights to create views.

Comment: No, it is for this one. One possible workaround is to have a view that just selects from your table, with an `instead of` trigger than does the substr as part of the insert into the real table. But as you can't change the application, that has to currently be accessing the table in a way that lets you trick it into using the view instead, based on name resolution order. If you can add info to the question about how the application connects to the DB and runs the insert, that would be helpful.

Comment: Oooo sneaky!  I suspect it will get vetoed as too confusing, but it's a neat idea.  To answer your question, the application is connecting as the table owner.

Comment: Then you can't do that, unfortunately; you can't have a view with the same name as the table in the same schema, and the table will take precedence over a synonym. Shame.

Comment: Is there a place somewhere in the Oracle doc where it is mentioned ?

Answer (score -1):

Include the case statement similar to the following code in your insert command

```
insert into test_table
  (column1)
values
(  
  (case when length('ablekkkkkkkkkkkh') > 2000 then substr('ablekkkkkkkkh',1,2000)
   else 'ablekkkkkkkkkkkh' end )
);
```